# Any method for Elasticsearch query popularity?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I am new to Elasticsearch and making search suggestion to search for videos and right now using following query (I am using Elastica Library so its just a printed array)

```
[query] => Array
    (
        [query_string] => Array
            (
                [query] => Mac Os
                [default_field] => title
            )

    )


[fields] => Array
    (
        [0] => title
        [1] => videoid
    )

[from] => 0
[size] => 5
```

This gives me some quiet relevant results "Mac OSx" "Mac OS Lion" etc..
My question is,how can i add my own scoring or rating for indexed values..e.g if someone search for "Mac OS Lion", I can increase its popularity by 1 so it should come on top the next time Or is there any better alternative?

P.S I am also new to ElasticSearch Terms and perhaps the reason i am not able find the solution the yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElasticSearch provides a variety of mechanisms to boost the score of a document or term, such as:

- [Custom Boost Factor Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-boost-factor-query.html)
- [Custom Score Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query.html)
- [Boosting Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/boosting-query.html)

The general idea is that you boost a document's score depending on the value of a field or fields.  In your case, you may want to have a "popularity" field that is updated and used to boost the doc's value.  It depends on how you implement your code internally.

[This tutorial shows how to implement "Featured Results"](http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/01/24/Implementing_Featured_Results_With_ElasticSearch.html), which is a similar concept.  They used the [Constant Score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/constant-score-query.html).